Issue: Markers and User Location Not Displaying Consistently on Map in React Native
I am using react-native-maps (version 1.20.1) in my React Native project, and I am facing an issue where markers and the user location (blue dot) are not displaying consistently.
The first time I load the app (after clearing the Expo cache with npx expo start -c), everything works fine, but on subsequent reloads or when I navigate back to the map screen, the markers and user location disappear. Occasionally, they appear randomly but are not consistent.
At first i tried to debug using the logs
useEffect(() => {
  if (markers) {
    console.log("Markers loaded ", markers);
  }
}, [markers]);

in the terminal is said the Markers Loaded and with markers info but nothing was shown in the Map Page.
Then I thought the issue was with the AsyncStorage, so thought to clear it.
const clearStorage = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.clear();
      console.log('AsyncStorage cleared!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to clear AsyncStorage:', error);
    }
  };

  // Clear AsyncStorage when the app loads
  useEffect(() => {
    clearStorage();
  }, []);

still did not work as expected.

Try to make sure that the map is not being rendered twice. Add a constant key to your MapView Component to make sure there is only one instance of the map:
<MapView
   key={"map-instance"}
   ...
/>


I'm having the exact same issue. This is not an answer to your question, but I think the problem comes from the update to Expo 52 with the new architecture, which, as far as I understand it, is unavoidable if you wanna use Expo Go for testing. They're working on it, but there isn't a proper solution yet. You can browse through this issue on the react-native-maps github for more information:
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/5206
If you've found something that works in the meantime, I'd love to hear it
